# What is the Generic Drive that keeps beeping on and off

Tags: boot, drivers, usb, mount, malware

### Symptoms:

- Once booted and logged in: Computer beeps (same as attaching an
  external USB drive) then beeps (same as detaching an external USB
  drive). Frequent. Erratic. (Annoying. Worrisome: is something failing
  in the USB system?)
- The beeps happened with 20.04 LTS encrypted drive, I shut off system
  sounds.
- It started again with a fresh install of 22.04.1 LTS, ZFS encrypted,
  Secure Boot EFI.
- I had Disks open once when it beeps in: a Generic Storage Device shows up.

### Generic Storage Device Info:

- No Media. But mounted at /dev/disk/by-id/usb-GENERIC_STORAGE_DEVICE_0000000000819-0:0
- It disappears quickly.

I catch it when it stays long enough:

- On the Gears only the **Mount Options** is available. Tried lots, no effect.

### Mount options are

- /dev/sdc
- /dev/disk/by-id/usb-GENERIC_STORAGE_DEVICE_0000000000819-0:0
- /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0

### On Top Bar:

- only **Power Off** has any effect: Generic disappears, but it
  comes back. (Very concerning. Is this malware?)

### Clam

**Clam** shows the system clean.

### Questions:

- What is this? (Hardware failure in the USB system? Driver Glitch? Malware?)
- How do I find out?
- How do I stop it?

Or is it Ubuntu somehow? A setting or feature? (Like the login that kept popping up at gnome.org? Stopped that.)

2 Images of Disks repeated in info above
[Generic Storage Displays In DISKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RnKe.jpg)
[Mount Point Options in Disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbYNE.jpg)

### Further Information

```
dmesg | grep usb
```

provides lots of information. The device is listed as connecting and disconnecting many times.
There's an error -22 in there. I've taken out lines that I recognize belong to other devices (indicated with ...), like the mouse. I've left in information that is upstream, ie. controllers and hubs etc.

```
[    0.272163] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.272163] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.341618] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    0.341620] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.341622] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.341632] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-43-generic ehci_hcd
[    0.341633] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    0.361590] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    0.361592] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.361594] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.361595] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-43-generic ehci_hcd
[    0.361596] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    0.677556] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    0.697558] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
...
[    1.047588] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.047590] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-43-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.047592] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.063313] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.063315] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.063316] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.063317] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-43-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.063318] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
...
[    1.685558] usb 3-5: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.839547] usb 3-5: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
[    1.839553] usb 3-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3004, bcdDevice= 0.02
[    1.839556] usb 3-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    3.485785] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    3.508110] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[    3.508116] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[    3.508118] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[    3.508120] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[    3.508121] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[    3.514031] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    3.514151] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[    3.514205] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
...
[   13.583985] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   14.325822] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   14.348249] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[   14.348255] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[   14.348257] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[   14.348259] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[   14.348260] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[   14.350504] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   14.350832] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[   27.921995] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   27.948024] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[  136.213651] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
...
[  136.443290] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[  167.470827] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  168.201782] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  168.224576] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[  168.224587] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[  168.224592] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[  168.224595] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[  168.224598] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[  168.226969] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  168.227380] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[  185.893877] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  215.221792] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  215.244453] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[  215.244467] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[  215.244472] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[  215.244477] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[  215.244481] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[  215.248676] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  215.248959] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[  231.213852] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  364.481715] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  364.503699] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[  364.503704] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[  364.503706] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[  364.503707] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[  364.503709] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[  364.507231] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  364.507422] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[  483.935776] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 6
[  484.693728] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  484.716381] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[  484.716388] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[  484.716391] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[  484.716393] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[  484.716395] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[  484.718674] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  484.719022] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[  702.185053] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 7
[  702.963576] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  702.986065] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[  702.986070] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[  702.986072] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[  702.986074] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[  702.986075] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[  702.988234] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  702.988470] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[  715.794385] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 8
[  967.131457] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  967.153860] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[  967.153866] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[  967.153868] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[  967.153869] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[  967.153870] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[  967.155921] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  967.156124] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[ 1008.248260] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 9
[ 1009.023980] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 1009.050483] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[ 1009.050494] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[ 1009.050498] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[ 1009.050501] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 1009.050504] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[ 1009.052875] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1009.053231] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[ 1225.647528] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 10
[ 1226.388779] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[ 1226.414925] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[ 1226.414930] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[ 1226.414932] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[ 1226.414934] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 1226.414935] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[ 1226.416918] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1226.417096] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[ 1259.566892] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 11
[ 1260.251707] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 1260.277644] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[ 1260.277649] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[ 1260.277650] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[ 1260.277651] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 1260.277652] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[ 1260.279701] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1260.279875] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[ 1677.257750] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 12
[ 1678.034192] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 1678.056297] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[ 1678.056305] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[ 1678.056308] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[ 1678.056310] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 1678.056312] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[ 1678.058413] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1678.058520] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[ 2214.943820] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 13
[ 2215.643661] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[ 2215.665899] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[ 2215.665910] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[ 2215.665914] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[ 2215.665917] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 2215.665920] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[ 2215.668237] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2215.668435] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[ 2230.003387] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 14
[ 2432.546870] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[ 2432.569008] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[ 2432.569013] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[ 2432.569015] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[ 2432.569017] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 2432.569018] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[ 2432.571024] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2432.571203] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[ 2444.419383] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 15
[ 2685.179299] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[ 2685.201344] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[ 2685.201352] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[ 2685.201355] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[ 2685.201358] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 2685.201360] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[ 2685.204381] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2685.204694] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[ 2694.695013] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 16
[ 2957.900079] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[ 2957.922354] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[ 2957.922359] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[ 2957.922361] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[ 2957.922363] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 2957.922364] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[ 2957.924496] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2957.924668] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[ 3470.427850] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 17
[ 3471.194193] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[ 3471.216602] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[ 3471.216614] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[ 3471.216619] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[ 3471.216623] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 3471.216627] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[ 3471.219134] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3471.219521] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[ 3566.254179] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 18
[ 3567.030401] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[ 3567.053026] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0747, bcdDevice= 8.19
[ 3567.053032] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[ 3567.053035] usb 4-4: Product: USB Storage
[ 3567.053037] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 3567.053038] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[ 3567.055155] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3567.055428] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-4:1.0
[ 4239.066460] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 19
[ 9496.385198] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
```

Comment: Probably this will output just some generic info, but in case that it gives a meaningful output, can you add the output of `dmesg >> random_output_name`? It will be too long, so the last past directs it to a file, and you can grab the whole output to post in here. You can paste it in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) and share the link.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to disable the USB device. ***This is not a solution, instead a mitigation.***

This mitigation comes from this [guide.](http://migueleonardortiz.com.ar/linux/learning-how-to-disable-specific-usb-devices-by-their-ports-in-linux/1645)

First, find the `uevent number` associated with the device, there are two methods for finding it.

1.(First Method) Get it from `dmesg`. The part after `usb` is the associated number, so `4-4`:

```
[ 1678.034192] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
```

1.(Second Method) Find the bus and device number that it is connected via `lsusb`

```
Bus XXX Device YYY: ID 05e3:0747 Generic USB Storage
```

then

```
grep -l XXX/YYY /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/uevent
```

This will output `4-4`.

After this step everything is the same.

2. Set this uevent number to be turned off.

```
echo '4-4' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

See if this mitigates the issue for the current session. If it does, then on the guide it explains how to turn this into a script to repeat it after every reboot. If you can't create the script, let me know, and I'll write the script.

Comment: It is possible to disable USB-Storage devices, but that disables every USB-Storage device. So when you need to plug a USB-Storage, you'll need to re-enable it and after you are done re-disable it.