# Constant USB connection and disconnection sound on Ubuntu 22.04LST

Tags: sound, realtek, dmesg, alienware, scsi

I have a Alienware Dell R4 and i installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10.
There is a constant sound that appears to be the power charger connection/disconnection. However i don't think i have issues with it.

I've ran the "dmesg" command several times and every time the sound comes there are these lines. Apparently it comes from the USB 2-2:

```
[ 1546.508919] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 1546.509086] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
[ 1546.881053] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 1546.913098] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0328, bcdDevice=29.08
[ 1546.913110] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1546.913116] usb 2-2: Product: USB3.0-CRW
[ 1546.913120] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 1546.913124] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 28203008282014000
[ 1546.921132] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1546.921892] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[ 1547.955446] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- SD/MMC CRW       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1547.956045] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[ 1547.957560] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Media removed, stopped polling
[ 1547.959856] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I have research about it but had no luck so far.

Please, any clue is highly appreciated. The sound appears with high frequency.

Updated the dmesg text i get every time there is that sound. Looks like comes from a USB3.
Still researching.

thank you!

Comment: Kind of a similar situation with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424553/what-is-the-generic-drive-that-keeps-beeping-on-and-off/1424807) ("ghost" drives). Linking for possible bug report that needs more investigation.

Comment: Thank you @EmreTalha

Comment: Hi @guiverc Yes, I am using Ubuntu 22.04LST.
Was researching about it but there is no much information. Do you have any clue please?

Comment: Sure, thank you for the advice @guiverc  !